# Derivative of matrix logarithm with respect to matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, logarithms, matrix-calculus

I saw in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1375251/optimization-on-se3-with-matrix-logarithm) that 
 
$\frac{d}{dt}\text{logm}(Z(t)) = \frac{dZ(t)}{dt}(Z(t))^{-1}$

Is this true to say: 
$\frac{d}{{dU}}{\mathop{\rm logm}\nolimits} (A) = {A^{ - 1}}\frac{d}{{dU}}A$

where U is an m by n matrix and A is an m by m matrix which is a function of U ?

EDIT: A is not Symmetric and positive definite.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those statements is true.

However, you can use a block triangular matrix to calculate the Frechet derivative using the method of Kenney & Laub
$${\rm F}\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}Z&E\\0&Z\end{bmatrix}\Bigg) =  \begin{bmatrix}F&L\\0&F\end{bmatrix} $$
where $F = {\rm F}(Z)$ and $$L = \lim_{dt\rightarrow\,0}\, \frac{{\rm F}(Z+E\,dt)-{\rm F}(Z)}{dt}$$
For your particular case
$$\eqalign{
 F &= {\rm logm}(Z) \cr
 E &= \frac{dZ}{dt} \cr
}$$
$Z$, $F$ and $E$ must be evaluated at the same moment in time, e.g. $t=t_0$.

This will give you the directional derivative of the function, in the $E$-direction.

Comment: thanks, does this method works if A is not Symmetric and positive definite?

Comment: The method works for any matrix, for which you can evaluate the function.